# getActivity() из фрагмента при перезапуске возвращает null

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

**UPD**

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_activity);
        mainFragment = new MainScreenFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_frame, mainFragment)
            .commit();
    }
```

**Фрагмент**

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
1:      redraw();
2:      getAccidents();
    }

    private void redraw(){
        Accidents.getVisible()
                 .subscribe(a -> listContent.addView(
3:                     Rows.getAccidentRow(getActivity(), listContent, a)
                  ));
    }
    private void getAccidents() {
        startRefreshAnimation(); //ProgressBar on
        Accidents.updated //подписка на Subject<Boolean>
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //Для ProgressBar
                .subscribe(b -> {
                        stopRefreshAnimation(); //ProgressBar off
                        redraw();
                 });
        Accidents.update(); //запуск сетевого запроса, который по окончанию зашлет true в подписку строкой выше
    }
```

По шагам:

1. Запуская приложение. Все отрабатывает без проблем.
2. Закрываю приложение кнопкой `back`.
3. Запускаю заново.
4. Строка `1:` отрабатывает.
5. Строка `2:` отрабатывает, но в строке `3:` на этот раз `getActivity()` возвращает `null`

Собственно вопрос, почему при одном и том же коде косяк происходит именно при перезапуске приложения?

Comment: Возможно у вас первый фрагмент ещё в памяти остался и при следующем зупаске вы его меняете на второй. Попробуйте в onCreate активити при добавлении фрагмента проверять не добавлен ли он уже. Например так: `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_frame) != null`

Comment: На схемки не нужно пулювать слюнями, что бы ни стояло за этим действием, вызов колбэков жизненного цикла происходит строго последовательно, согласно схемки. Предположить, что они вызываются "как попало" (асинхронно) говорит лишь о недостаточном понимании происходящего.

Comment: @pavlofff ну так объясните, почему после `onCreateActivity` и `onAttach`  `getActivity()` возвращает `null`

Comment: В том коде, что находится в вашем вопросе, нет причин для описанного поведения. Проблема по этому коду не воспроизводится. Очевидно проблема в другом месте.

Comment: Предлагаю сначала перенести получение `getActivity()` в сам метод `onResume()` и присвоить там полю класса. В дальнейшем обращаться к этому полю, а не через метод. Если не поможет, предлагаю исключить обращения к RxJava константами и проверить состояние метода `getActivity()`, я практически уверен, что проблемы не будет. Если так, то проблему нужно искать в самом Rx

Comment: @pavlofff делал, не помогло. Даже если `static` делать, все одно `null`, что совсем уж странно.

Comment: @pavlofff посмотрите мой ответ пожалуйста, может возникнут какие либо идеи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

Работать заставил, но решение вызывает больше вопросов, чем дает ответов.

Если кратко, то организовал подписку на контекст из метода `onAttach()`

```
private        FragmentActivity mActivity;
public  static Subject<Context> isAttached = PublishSubject.create();

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mActivity = (FragmentActivity) context;
    isAttached.onNext(mActivity);
}

public void redraw() {
    isAttached.subscribe(context -> {
                             listContent.removeAllViews();
                             Log.e("FRAGMENT", String.valueOf(this.isAdded()));
                             Accidents.getVisible()
                                      .sorted((a, b) -> MyUtils.reverseComparator(a.id, b.id))
                                      .subscribe(a -> listContent.addView(Rows.getAccidentRow(context, listContent, a)));
                             map.placeAccidents(context);
                         }
                        );
    if (mActivity != null) isAttached.onNext(mActivity);
}
```

Причем `Log.e("FRAGMENT", String.valueOf(this.isAdded()));` возвращает `false` в то время, когда `context` уже есть. Подозреваю, что как-то вся эта мистика связана с восстановлением из `savedInstanceState` но доказать не могу

Answer (score 0):

Добавлять Fragment к Activity нужно только при первом запуске Activity. Проверить первый раз запускается Activity или нет можно через параметр savedInstanceState метода onCreate, если он null - значит можно добавлять фрагмент.

Измените onCreate метод вашего Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_activity);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         mainFragment = new MainScreenFragment();
         getSupportFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.main_frame, mainFragment)
             .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @rjhdby Нет, создан ранее фрагмент или нет не является проблемой  поведения в вопросе. тем более, что при закрытии кнопкой "назад" активити (и созданные ей классы, включая фрагмент) уничтожается. Очевидно, проблема с RxJava, но я с ней не работаю и понять, почему так происходит не помогу.

Comment: Метод getActivity может возвращать null только если Fragment не прикреплен ни к одной Activity. В каком случае такое может произойти я написал в ответе выше. Проверить или Fragment прикреплен к Activity можено через метод Fragment.isAdded().

Comment: Не помогло, та же ошибка